# Downloading coordinates in json from RESTFUL service

Tags: android, json, rest, download

I've set up an application on the android platform which actually downloads from the web service as json format. Currently the application can download from the web service and placing the items on the list view.

The main purpose of the application is downloading the parameters in the json which contains coordinate x-y,then plotting the x-y onto a drawview in another class.

Can anyone please assist me on how to accomplish it? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) paradigm was designed to do stuff just like this. I suggest you take a look at that example and watch one of my favorite Google IO videos ever: [Android REST client Applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the JSON string or object, use JSONObject to then work with the json itself. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html its very intuitive and easy to use. Are you senting a POST to a server ? also is the information you are receiving from a common API? if so there are several wrappers / sdks available for different apis